# CSS Onclick Close (display none) Not Working, Responsive Design

Tags: javascript, html, css, sidebar, w3c

I'm following the w3 tutorials and exploring a responsive design template here (see source code for details): https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryw3css_templates_analytics.htm

I'd like to edit the sidebar so that a close button is always displayed, and close the sidebar when clicked. Under it's current design, this only works for the mid-size and small windows.

I tried revising the code to remove the hidden class (so it's always displayed). However, the function does not close the sidebar when clicked:

From:

```
<a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-16 w3-hide-large w3-dark-grey w3-hover-black" onclick="w3_close()" title="close menu">
  <i class="fa fa-remove fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; Close Menu
</a>
```

To:

```
<a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding w3-dark-grey w3-hover-black" onclick="w3_close();return false;" title="close side menu">
  <i class="fa fa-remove fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; Close Menu
</a>
```

I'm missing something very elementary here. But I've fiddled with this long enough I'd like to get pointed in the right direction. The code is right, I'm guessing this may be a DOM or bubbling issue, or basic design edit? Thanks!

Comment: Btw, the World Wide Web Consortium (W3C) is *not* w3schools in the slightest. w3schools is a notoriously not-entirely-reliable tutorial/docs site (often leading users towards bad practices, which can be seen in the code above). The W3C is the internet's standards organization.

Comment: You're right. I'll edit to clarify. I think I mistyped that as much as anything. It's w3, not w3c. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be an `!important` media query CSS rule that's probably blocking your styling from having effect:

```
@media (min-width: 993px)
.w3-sidebar.w3-collapse {
     display: block!important;
}
```

I did a `document.querySelector("#mySidebar").style.display = "none"` and it had no effect.  You could remove that `!important` rule or otherwise work around it...

Comment: also you need to take care of `<div class="w3-main" style="margin-left:300px;margin-top:43px;">` and need to remove/modify margin-left from it so that page should look responsive to hiding sidebar action.

Comment: Thanks Scott, and sandeep joshi. Both work. I just added to the close function to remove the margin-left styling. I can say, that I'm not sure I would have figured out the !important blocking the action. Makes me wonder how many other similar hurdles would exist. How did you zero-in on that being the culprit?

Comment: np!  I went to the w3 site, noticed the behavior you mentioned, and tried `document.querySelector("#mySidebar").style.display = "none"` right in the Dev Tools console.  But when that did nothing, I right-clicked the NavBar to inspect element and I noticed that `!important` rule was overriding the inline CSS.